# Akkusative in "wie lange dauert am Freitag der Unterricht"?

Tags: grammaticality

I was wondering if the sentence

> Wie lange dauert am Freitag unseren Unterricht?

is correct. Do I have to use Akkusativ in this case like I did or not? 
Does "unseren Unterricht" go before or after "am Freitag"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct is:

> Wie lange dauert am Freitag unser Unterricht?

Because "unser Unterricht" is the subject of the sentence, it has to be nominative.

> Wie lange dauert unser Unterricht am Freitag?

is also correct. Because *Freitag* is last, there is some emphasis on it.

Comment: thanks ! So " wann haben wir unser Urlaub it's correct too ?

Comment: No, here *wir* is the subject and *Urlaub* is the accusative object, so it has to be "unseren Urlaub".